# Counting PHP array values, only first one works?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array:

```
print_r($mCOneC);
```

> => Array ( [0] => start [1] => Trial [2] => Refusal [3] => Expel [4] => Mouth Clean )

If I do:

```
$length = count( array_keys( $mCOneC, 'start' ));

echo $length;
```

I get: `1`

If I do:

```
$length = count( array_keys( $mCOneC, 'Trial' ));

echo $length;
```

I get: `0`

Any reason why this is not working?

Comment: Please help us by providing how you defined (built) your array.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. How do you create the array?

Comment: At my localhost both Lenghts have result = 1 ...

Comment: Are you sure the `Trial` value in the array isn't `Trial[space]` or otherwise has an invisible/unprintable character in it, making it something OTHER than `Trial`? a var_dump of the array will show its string length, and it SHOULD be 5. if it's not, then it's not just 'Trial'.

Comment: Array was built from a db result:
$mCOneC = $row['mCOneC'];

$mCOneC = explode(",",$mCOneC);

Comment: Can you add `$mCOneC` as string before you ran explode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple you are dealing with space

```
$mCOneC = Array(
        0 => "start",
        1 => "Trial ",
        2 => "Refusal",
        3 => "Expel",
        4 => "Mouth Clean");


$mCOneC = array_map("trim", $mCOneC); <------------- Fix Spaces
$length = count( array_keys( $mCOneC, 'start' ));
var_dump($length);


$length = count( array_keys( $mCOneC, 'Trial' ));
var_dump($length);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `array_keys` does not lie to you. For your second example you're having an issue with returning zero:

```
count(array_keys($mCOneC, 'Trial'));
```

This just means that the array `$mCOneC` does not contain any string that is exactly `'Trial'`. You need to more thoroughly inspect the original data why it does not match, for example with the `var_dump` function on the concrete value:

```
var_dump($mCOneC[1]);
```

This should shed more light into your issue. The `print_r` function you use is not that specific as `var_dump`. Also take care when viewing things inside the browser window, take a look into the source-view of your browser, too. It's displaying things better than the browser window when you need to debug.